# How to convert grayscale image matrix to image in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, grayscale

I have a matrix of values representing an 8-bit grayscale image (values range from 0 to 255). I would like to display this image on the web. How can I do so? The image is coming from a C program, would this require converting the image in the C program?

Comment: check the image codecs [here](https://github.com/foo123/FILTER.js) and choose one to save the data as actual image on disk, https://github.com/foo123/FILTER.js/tree/master/src/codecs

Comment: note not all codecs support encoding (saving data as image), some support only encoding (reading data from image)

Comment: Im reading about the codecs here https://github.com/foo123/FILTER.js/blob/master/api-reference.md#codecs Where do I pass the matrix? Do you recommend a specific format

Comment: these codecs are adapted versions of codecs found gere and there (plus a couple custom coded). The format used is the pixel matrix array, but they are fine-tuned to work with filter.js, either adapt them (easy) or check original sources

Comment: How do I know which support decoding?

Comment: they have a encoder method, else encoder is NotImplemented, easy to see

Comment: Look at pngjs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs

Comment: @stdob would you be able to help with my latest question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259142/how-to-use-pngjs-library-to-create-png-from-rgb-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the pngjs library to do the job thanks to stdob's suggestion https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs. Heres the code I used:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;

var png = new PNG({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    filterType: -1
});

for (var y = 0; y < png.height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < png.width; x++) {
        var idx = (png.width * y + x) << 2;
        png.data[idx  ] = 255;
        png.data[idx+1] = 218;
        png.data[idx+2] = 185;
        png.data[idx+3] = 255;
    }
}

png.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('newOut.png'));
```